# Delphi x64 embedded database

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Googled for a long time but cant seem to find an answer.
Is there any x64 embedded database to use with Delphi ?
Cant seem to find any

Comment: as a matter of fact,I need something to use with Delphi XE2

Comment: Are you looking for a true 64 bit database engine or a driver to support a 32 bit database engine on a 64 bit platform? Are you compiling 64 bit applications?

Comment: I am looking for a 64 bit database engine. Something I can create tables with. I am compiling 64 application.

Comment: why does delphi xe2 have  jet4 driver which is used for +mdb databases ? And x64 compiles using *.mdb ? Strange indeed ...

Comment: I haven't worked with XE2 (will wait a year or so until they straighten everything out...) But I've been working with Win64, workstations and servers with Delphi XE and I do know that Win64 will automatically detect a 32bit module and run it under WOW64 - so there may be stuff that you think is running 64bit but isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [AnyDAC](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/) 5.0.3 with XE2 and 64-bit support. SQLite is already included into library installer.

> Embedded:
>
> - SQLite Database
> - Firebird Embedded
> - MySQL Embedded
> - Berkeley DB
> - Advantage Local

Answer (score 6):

Delphi XE 2 [supports FireBird 2.5](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Database_Changes_for_XE2) using [dbExpress](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/DbExpress_4_Feature_Overview), So try the [Firebird x64 Embedded version](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5/#Win64).

Comment: I honestly dont know what to download from that page.

Comment: try this link http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-win64/2.5-Release/Firebird-2.5.0.26074-0_x64_embed.zip/download

Comment: I'd better use Unified Interbase. It needs some attention to dive in (to choose functionality needed and IfDef it. I also patched DLL load function) but less indirection levels - more speed and simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

Devart have a [dbExpress driver for sqlite](http://www.devart.com/dbx/sqlite/) that supports XE2 64 bit targets.

Comment: it seems I need to get a nervous breakdown before I figure what to download and how it works. It seems no one has a normal embedded database which can be edited,something like absolute database. To get a normal installer is,it seems, too much to ask.

Comment: A comment on the reasoning behind the downvote would be helpful to everyone

Comment: @user the answer received a downvote. You can't see that because you aren't able to split out upvotes and downvotes individually yet (not enough rep).

Comment: I noticed a strange thing ... i have Office 2010 x64. I can link my x64 application  to a *.mdb database which is strange indeed.... *.mdb database is usually x32 and used in older office versions.

Comment: I am new to this site so i am having hard time to figure how everything functions.

Comment: No, .mdb databases can be read happily by both 32 and 64 bit Office.

Answer (score 0):

Among free embedded engines there is also Nexus DB to be listed.

http://www.nexusdb.com/support/index.php?q=node/509

People worked with v2 told that the choice is dubious:

- only works good with their own Heap Manager
- In client-server mode high chance of DB corruption when Windows terminates program
- On large (hundreds thousand of rows) table queries, all the data is pulled to memory and only filtered later, if not dieing for not enough memory, cache never shrinks back then. This also makes it work rather slow.

People worked with v3 mostly tell that is hollywar and totally outdated claims.

Up to me, if to need on disk persistence, then go to Firebird Embedded + Unified Interbase library. If to need relatively small in-memory tables with little latency - then NexusDB Embedded would be free and natively-integrating suite.